# Как узнать нужен ли PULL для текущей ветки?

Tags: git, bash

Допустим у меня две основные ветки **master** и **dev** которые работают в разных папках. Периодически **dev** сливается в **master**, хотя бывают редкие случае когда hotfix прямо в **master** делается и потом подтягивается в **dev**. И вот мне нужен скрипт деплоя, который срабатывает **только** в том случае когда изменения пушнули в конкретную ветку. И ничего не делал если что-то происходит в других ветках.

Как пример рассмотрим сценарий который сработает только когда был push в dev, либо merge другой ветки в dev, и который не сработает при push в master или дочернюю ветку.

Comment: pull = fetch+merge. Раз fetch уже выполнен, достаточно сделать `git merge origin/${BRANCH}`. Это избавит от второго запроса по сети.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я исхожу из следующих допущений, которые почерпнул из вопроса.

- К репозиторию подключен только один удаленный репозиторий под названием `origin`.
- Текущая ветка синхронизируется с веткой `dev`.

В таком случае алгоритм будет следующий:

1. Выполнить `git fetch`. Команда без параметров. Она затянет все изменения из удаленного репозитория в локальный без изменения рабочей копии. Только после этого можно будет узнать изменилась ли ветка `origin/dev` или нет.
2. Сравнить HEAD и origin/dev. Для этого, например, можно сравнить вывод команд `git rev-parse HEAD` и `git rev-parse origin/dev` (к сожалению, не знаю как это делается на bash).
3. Если не равны, то:

   - подготовительные действия, например, остановка сервера
   - `git merge --ff-only origin/dev`. Параметр `--ff-only` обеспечит, что, во-первых, не будет создан лишний коммит слияния, во-вторых, произойдет ошибка, если в ветке `origin/dev` кто-то переставлял коммиты вручную или если локально на сервере кто-то делал коммиты и не смерхил их с `origin/dev`.
   - завершающие действия, например, старт сервера.

**PS** если нужно, локальные коммиты на сервере запрещены, и если кто-то их наделал, то нужно их отбросить, а в `origin/dev` могут менять коммиты после публикации, то merge можно заменить на `git reset --hard origin/dev`

Comment: Если можно, то с примером. первый  и второй пункт. Я не Git гуру

Comment: @Ninazu, подправил ответ.